# Magento: Detailed Image on Mouse-over for Product Attribute

Tags: magento

I would like to show a detailed image on mouseover for each of our options.

This is exactly what i am after:
http://www.potterybarn.com.au/textured-solid-pillow-cover

Any idea on how to do that? Or is there a plugin available for that?

Answer (score 1):

Detailed image is usually called product zoom function and it's present in most of magento themes including default ones. It shows original image on zoom function and smaller version of the same image by default.

Images for options function is called color swatch, most of the modules aren't free. But the recent magento 1.9.1 has this feature for free in their new default theme called rwd. There are both color swatch and product image zoom features. You can look how they've done it and extend their solution if you need something more

The easiest way to achieve option image itself on hover would be to use image of resolution you need to have on hover in your configurable product. Then change html of configurable swatch options file. Currently it shows just one image, you can add the same image wrapped in some block. Then change the size of one image to be small, hide block hide big one and show it on hover via css/js.

File with code for swatches: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml`

Comment: I am actually after the Configurable Product with PopUp Boxes but the rwd plugin doesn't have it. Any suggestion?

Comment: That's the closest free thing I'm aware of. It doesn't sound very challenging to implement though, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks I look forward to your answer. I am still new to coding, look forward to learn from you and get better.

Comment: @Kin well, by the time you wrote the last comment I had already updated my answer (the last two paragraphs). I'm not that experienced myself, but I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/swatches-list.js

```
and change line no: 52 "click" to "mouseover"

Then check, if correct please vote me.

Thanks.
```